# Preload wont load on some browsers

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, preload

Okay, so i created fingerprint scanner animation with effect you need to click fingerprint and then goes animation like fingerprint is filling and in 5 sec redirect you to website, thats working great on google and other browsers, but on samsung mobile browser it wont show, showing like 1 big correct icon but not fingerprint how can i fix it?
Tysm <3

Comment: Welcome to SO, I would checkout [mcve]

Comment: Sorry i only asking like is there way to put smtng in code to fix samsung browser

Comment: If people can't see the code that you are using, no one can assist you in providing a solution.

Comment: Idk what to put? My fingerprint or smtng?

Comment: The basic code that is used to create the fingerprint animation

Comment: Before i put i will ask, is there way to fix samsung browser

Comment: Without seeing the code, no one can help you.

Comment: here is the code :

Comment: @imvain2
HTML - https://pastebin.com/wYtXzdNp
CSS - https://pastebin.com/j95QEJfZ
JS - https://pastebin.com/g5vdFveZ